# Break Tags in Drupal8 Menu Items

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I want to add break tags in menu item titles.

I added one menu item with title as "test 
 cases". But it is not considering html tags in title. It is displaying as normal text.

my menu-main.html.twig file is like this. It is always skipping html tags in my title. If any one knows solution for this , please help me.

```
 {#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a menu.
 */
#}
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html

  1. We use menu_name (see above) to create a CSS class name from it.
  See https://www.drupal.org/node/2649076
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0, menu_name) }} {# 1. #}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level, menu_name) %} {# 1. #}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {# 1. #}
  {%
    set menu_classes = [
      'animenu__nav',
      'c-menu-' ~ menu_name|clean_class,
    ]
  %}
  {# 1. #}
  {%
    set submenu_classes = [
      'o-menu',
      'animenu__nav__child',
    ]
  %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass(menu_classes) }}> {# 1. #}
    {% else %}
      <ul{{ attributes.removeClass(menu_classes).addClass(submenu_classes) }}> {# 1. #}
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {# 1. #}
      {%
        set item_classes = [
          'c-menu-' ~ menu_name|clean_class ~ '__item',
          item.is_expanded ? 'c-menu-' ~ menu_name|clean_class ~ '__item--expanded',
          item.is_collapsed ? 'c-menu-' ~ menu_name|clean_class ~ '__item--collapsed',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'c-menu-' ~ menu_name|clean_class ~ '__item--active-trail',
        ]
      %}
      {# 1. #}
      {%
        set link_classes = [
          'c-menu-' ~ menu_name|clean_class ~ '__link',
        ]
      %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }}>{# 1. #}
        {# 1. #}
        {{

          link(
            item.title,
            item.url,
            item.attributes.removeClass(item_classes).addClass(link_classes)
          )
        }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1, menu_name) }} {# 1. #}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this in your `THEMENAME.theme` file

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_menu(&$variables){
  foreach($variables['items'] as &$link){
  $link['title'] = Markup::create($link['title']);
 }
}
```

It should render html properly inside all your menu titles